# Find number by parsing html file

Tags: python, regex

This is kind of a specific question, but I have an html file (code coverage data) and I'd like to locate the last occurrence of a percentage in the file using Python regex. I figured out how to do it using grep, but I haven't been able to convert it to Python successfully.

Here is the grep statement that worked:

```
grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" coverage_results.html | tail -n1
```

This should match a 1 or 2 digit number followed by a % sign. There are multiple numbers in the html that match this, so I only want the last one. For all I know, there may even be a way to do it without piping to tail (maybe with awk?), but that was as far as I got.

My Python code looks like this so far:

```
 searchfile = open("coverage_results.html", "r")
    for line in searchfile:
        if re.search("(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))", line, re.M | re.I):
            print line
```

Some sample input:

```
html/api2/one.php</a></td><td>40</td><td>40</td><td>100%</td></tr><tr><td><a href="one.php.html">/var/lib/web/html/api2/two.php</a></td><td>114</td><td>117</td><td>97%</td></tr><tr><td><a href="two.php.html">/var/lib/web/html/api2/test.php</a></td><td>39</td><td>39</td><td>100%</td></tr><tr><td><a href="three.php.html">/var/lib/web/html/api2/test.php</a></td><td>55</td><td>55</td><td>100%</td></tr></table><p>Overall: 3461 / 5296 - 65%</p></body></html>
```

How do I return only the part of the string that matches?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Ideally just the last number that gets matched. So in the sample input, I'd like to see 65 or 65% returned.

Comment: And, some `<tag attr="..%2">` is ok then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're printing the line where the search matches. If instead you wanted some of the groups your code would need to look like this:

```
 searchfile = open("coverage_results.html", "r")
    for line in searchfile:
        regreturn = re.search("(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))", line, re.M | re.I)
        if regreturn is not None:
            print regreturn.groups()
```

Comment: Could I use this approach to print only the last group that got matched?

Comment: Sure, since `regreturn.groups` is a tuple, you could do `print regreturn.groups()[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a variation of AetherUnbound's answer:

```
searchfile = open("coverage_results.html", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    regreturn = re.findall(r"\d+%", line, re.M | re.I)
    if regreturn is not None:
        print regreturn[-1]
```

Comment: Err, what happened to all that `d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=%)` stuff ?

Comment: It would still work, but this is simpler and is easier to quickly read and understand. The only difference is that this solution returns percentages with 1 or more digits, instead of only 1 or 2.

Comment: Applications should not be governed by regex ease of understanding. If you need a regex, might as well learn how to use them else you will not reap the benefit's. For ease of understanding, start writing and inserting regex like the code that it is. http://www.regexformat.com instead of these unreadable 1 liners.